# Stop TSLint removing leading spaces within a HTML element

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tslint, linter

How do I configure TSLint in VSCode to not reformat my code?  I don't want to disable TSLint entirely I just want to stop this one thing it does.
 I want to keep the leading indentation within the html tags.

```html
        <ng-template [ngIf]="($eventsCount | async) > 0">
            <a href=""
                *ngIf="!($isClosing | async)"
                class="btn--danger"
                confirm="Are you sure?"
                (confirmed)="onCloseAll()">
                Close All
            </a>
        </ng-template>
```

When I save the above code TSLint ( in VSCode ) reformats it to this:

```html
        <ng-template [ngIf]="($eventsCount | async) > 0">
            <a href="" *ngIf="!($isClosing | async)" class="btn--danger" confirm="Are you sure?" (confirmed)="onCloseAll()">
                Close All
            </a>
        </ng-template>
```

What rule do I need to change in TSLint to stop it removing the leading spaces in my angular components html?

TSLint version: 5.9.1

Thanks

Comment: TSLint is just for TypeScript, not HTML. VSCode uses a formatter based on js-beautify for HTML https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not TSLint - this is probably the default HTML formatter in VS Code. You likely have formatOnSave set to true, you can disable it completely, or for certain filetypes:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
  "[html]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```

However I would recommend checking out [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode), they recently released an insanely powerful/configurable HTML formatter.